# Parsing user input including tz database time zone name

Tags: c#, timezone, nodatime

I'm attempting to parse user input with Noda Time.

Input:

- Date in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`
- Hour
- Minute
- tz database time zone name (returned from Google's Time Zone API)

I need to convert this data to UTC and to other time zones, also based on a tz database time zone name.

Currently I'm trying to make sense of the `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` differences, but perhaps someone is able to show how to do this before I'd (hopefully) figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is pretty close to what I'd do - but if you have the date, hour and minute in separate strings, I'd use:

```
var zoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
var sourceZone = zoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull("Europe/Brussels");
var targetZone = zoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull("Australia/Melbourne");

if (sourceZone == null || targetZone == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time zone not found");
    return;
}

var dateParseResult = LocalDatePattern.IsoPattern.Parse(date);
int hourValue, minuteValue;
if (!dateParseResult.Success ||
    !int.TryParse(hour, out hourValue) ||
    !int.TryParse(minute, out minuteValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsing failed");
    return;       
}

var localDateTime = dateParseResult.Value + new LocalTime(hour, minute);
var zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(sourceZone);
Console.WriteLine(zonedDateTime.ToInstant());
Console.WriteLine(zonedDateTime);
Console.WriteLine(zonedDateTime.WithZone(targetZone));
```

The only significant difference here is the parsing - I wouldn't stick all the bits together; I'd just parse the strings separately. (I also prefer "early outs" for failures :)

You should note the meaning of `InZoneStrictly` though - do you definitely want to fail if the input local date/time is ambiguous?

Comment: Thanks for your insights. We still have to decide how we'll handle ambiguous values, so I just used `InZoneStrictly` in my test program.

Comment: @Stijn: So long as you're aware of the possible problem and the options available, I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/02.aspx has great information, and while it's slightly outdated it's easy to find the relevant method names in the official documentation.

Below is some demonstration code.

```
string date = "2013-01-22";
string hour = "13";
string minute = "15";

var result = LocalDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern.Parse(date + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":00");

if (result.Success == true)
{
    DateTimeZone source_zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("Europe/Brussels");
    DateTimeZone target_zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("Australia/Melbourne");

    if (source_zone != null && target_zone != null)
    {
        ZonedDateTime source_zoned_dt = result.Value.InZoneStrictly(source_zone);

        Console.WriteLine(source_zoned_dt.ToInstant());
        Console.WriteLine(source_zoned_dt);
        Console.WriteLine(source_zoned_dt.WithZone(target_zone));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("time zone not found");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("parsing failed");
}
```